After reporting the snap error all snap installed apps got deleted
The first thing after booting my laptop I got a pop-up of some snap error which I then reported to the system (by system I mean the default report pop-up you get from Ubuntu).
After that, all installed snap applications got deleted immediately.
Have you faced such a problem and how to fix it?
The snap directory is not empty though.


for the record, i am using ubuntu 22.04

The question lacks enough useful detail be answerable. "some snap error" is not enough to work with.

I do not remember all the details, but it was i crash report.
I do agree with you, should have provide more details.
But unfortunately I have none at the moment.
Because I just submitted the report without saving, screening the details and etc.

I don't understand your picture either; snap ls is not a valid snap command, and thus I'd expect an error.  All I can think of is you added a 3rd party package which created a dependency problem which the package tools resolved via removal of snapd which would cause all snap packages to disappear - but that's the result of a user decision & 3rd party package install; and is resolved by correcting or changing the decision that caused it; and of this we have no details (this is based on very limited details & may not be what occurred)
